# JhtmlArea - Set html content

Tags: jquery, jhtmlarea

Hi I havce tried this:

```
$(function(){
   var descr = $("#area").htmlarea();
});

$("#some_button").click(function(){
  descr.pasteHTML("some text");
});
```

This don't work! How can I do ?? Thx!!

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, this has endless solutions... give us more detail. My two guesses:

`Are you including jQuery and the plugin js file?`

`Try wrapping all your code around the $(function(){`